# How to unInstall older versions of visual studio safely

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I kept on installing Visual Studio versions as they were released.
2010 and 2012 & 2013. Now I want to cleanup my system from older versions i.e. ( VS-2010 & VS-2012) & keep the latest one only!

```
How can I uninstall older versions safely without a need to re-install VS-2013.
```

P.S. I am afraid that if I un-install older versions that would delete some shared system files away which would be needed for VS-2013 to work properly.

Comment: Have you actually tried it or are you just wondering? I *think* they are all totally separate and so removing one shouldn't hurt the others. In fact, I uninstalled the express versions to replace with the professional version of 2013 and my 2010 installation works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by Mike in comments. I un-installed all previous versions prior to VS-2013. VS-2013 still works fine.

There was no dependency it seems.

Comment: When I try to remove the visual studio 2015 it asks me to close all instances of visual studio including 2017 ones. It's really dreadful to me.Are you sure thst that's OK !?

Comment: @Mohsen, when I answered this question it was VS 2015 or VS 2013. VS 2017 launched was not launched. Please Keep me posted how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has come up with [Force Uninstall Option](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2771441/EN-US#Force) to remove all remnants of Visual studio. This Will help you to remove previous versions of visual studio if any along with all other remnants including registry variables, which a normal UNINSTALL often fails to remove.

Comment: Upgrading has _never_ been difficult? I have had as many as four different version of VS on my machine!

Comment: John Saunders: Same here!

Comment: When I try to remove the visual studio 2015 it asks me to close all instances of visual studio including 2017 ones. It's really dreadful to me.Are you sure thst that's OK !?